# Laravel get input of dynamic created div

Tags: php, loops, laravel, model, laravel-5.1

I have created input elements using javascript, looks like this:

```
...
for(var i = 1; i<slider.value; i++) {
          +'<div class=\"input-group\">'
             +'<input id=\"input-chapter-start'+i+'\" type=\"text\">'
          +'</div>'
}
```

Now I am trying to get these dynamic created input ids in my model.

My Model looks like this so far.

```
protected $fillable = ['email', 'title', 'filename'];
```

My problem is now how to properly get the ids in the array.

I could not run something like this.

```
    protected $fillable = [
                    'email',
                    'title',
                    'filename',
                    for ($i=0; $i < ; $i++) { 
                        # code...
                    }
                    ];
```

EDIT:

My Model looks like this now:

```
protected $fillable = ['email', 'title', 'filename', 'input-chapter-start', 'input-chapter-end'];
```

In my Controller I get them like this:

```
   $chapterStartTime = Input::get('input-chapter-start');
   $chapterEndTime   = Input::get('input-chapter-end');
   dd($chapterStartTime);
```

Returns

> null

Comment: That's wrong.. Don't make a loop in `$fillable` just type the `id` only. Laravel will do the looping for you dynamically.

Comment: Strange does not work, keeps returning null if I dd that input

Comment: $chapterStartTime = Input::get('input-chapter-start1');
dd($chapterStartTime);

Comment: If I try to access a "static id" I get correct inputs, but the dynmic things does not work

Comment: Show us the rest of the code.

Comment: Ok edited question

Comment: I have it like this now:protected $fillable = ['email', 'title', 'filename', 'input-chapter-start', 'input-chapter-end'];

Comment: I get an error in the foreach, invalid argument supplied for foreach().
My foreach looks like this:        foreach($chapterStartTime as $value) {
            dd($value);
        }

Answer (score 1):

laravel can't get input value by id, you have to make input name `input-chapter-start[]`
should look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="input-chapter-start[]">
```

note, `[]` brackets mean that this input gets multiple values and it is array so you can make loop in your controller and get value of each input-chapter-start

Comment: also, if you are making relationship you can use attach function and laravel will save all input value as needed

Comment: hm ok what would my controller and model look like then?
just like this?
['input-chapter-end']; and in the controller like this?
       $chapterStartTime = Input::get('input-chapter-start');

Comment: your controller should like this
`$input = Input::get('input-chapter-start');
foreach($input as $i){
    // do what you want
}`

Comment: remove loop from fillable, just add column name

Comment: I have it like this now:protected $fillable = ['email', 'title', 'filename', 'input-chapter-start', 'input-chapter-end']; 
I get an error in the foreach, invalid argument supplied for foreach(). My foreach looks like this: foreach($chapterStartTime as $value) { dd($value); }

Comment: sorry `Input::get()` function cant get entire array value, use Request instead or make loop with `$input = Input::get('products.0');`,

Comment: how do I make such a loop, little confused right now

Comment: better use `Request` function instead of `Input`. 
should look like this:
`public function functionName(Request $request){` then `$request->inputName` and it gives you array

Comment: ok so it looks like this now: `code`    protected $request;

    public function request(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }`code`

Comment: Then I did this:        $lopo             = $this->request->input('input-chapter-start');
        dd($lopo);

        foreach($lopo as $value) {
            dd($value);
        }

Comment: and get this:
Call to a member function input() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add input element this way in js :

```
for(var i = 1; i<slider.value; i++) {
      +'<div class=\"input-group\">'
         +'<input name="did['+id+']" value="'+id+'" id=\"input-chapter-start'+i+'\" type=\"text\">'
      +'</div>'
```

}

And you can get dynamic array in controller or model like this way:

```
Input::get('did');
```

You can try...